# PHP Compress array of bits into shortest string possible

Tags: php, arrays, encoding, compression

I have an array that contains values of 1 or 0 representing true or false values. e.g.

```
array(1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1);
```

I want to compress/encode this array into the shortest string possible so that it can be stored within a space constrained place such as a cookie. It also need to be able to be decoded again later. How do I go about this?

ps. I am working in PHP

Comment: Depending on the maximum number of values, a combination of implode(), bindec() and pack() should give you the shortest possible length

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is my proposal:

```
$a = array(1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1);

$compressed = base64_encode(implode('', array_map(function($i) {
    return chr(bindec(implode('', $i)));
}, array_chunk($a, 8))));

var_dump($compressed); // string(8) "l8vlBw=="
```

So you get each 8 characters (which in fact is a binary `0..255`), convert them to an integer, represent as an ASCII character, implode it to a string and convert to base64 to be able to save it as a string.

**UPD**:

the opposite is pretty straightforward:

```
$original = str_split(implode('', array_map(function($i) {
    return decbin(ord($i));
}, str_split(base64_decode($compressed)))));
```

How exactly I wrote it (just in case anyone interesting how to write such unreadable and barely maintainable code):

I've written the `$original = $compressed;` and started reversing the right part of this expression step by step:

1. Decoded from base64 to a binary string
2. Split it to an array
3. Converted every character to its ASCII code
4. Converted decimal ASCII code to a binary
5. Joined all the binary numbers into a single one
6. Split the long binary string to an array

Comment: Beat me to it, this is basically the best option for OP.

Comment: Wow that looks great, do you have the reverse process?

Comment: @Chris: yep ;-) PS: as an *engineer* you should have done that yourself :-p

Comment: I'm sometimes not seeing the same result being decoded, for $a = array(1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1); i'm getting "1111001110011001111" back instead of "11110011010011001111"

Comment: Looks like it is an issue of losing leading 0's when converting decimal to binary, trying to write a solution now

Comment: I have posted an answer to my question using your answer but fixing the loss of leading 0's. I'm not sure if this is the best way of posting it, so please change if that is not appropriate. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Dont use serialize. Just make a string of it:

```
<?php

$string = implode( '', $array );
?>
```

You are left with an string like this:

```
100101111
```

If you want to have an array again, just access it like an array:

```
$string = '100101111';

echo $string[1]; // returns "0"

?>
```

Of course you could also make it a decimal and just store the number. That's even shorter then the "raw" bits.

```
<?php

$dec = bindec( $string );

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about [pack](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php) and [unpack](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php)

```
$arr = array(1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1);
$str = implode($arr);
$res = pack("h*", $str);
var_dump($res);
$rev = unpack("h*", $res);
var_dump($rev);
```

**output:**

```
string(10) # Not visible here
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  string(20) "11110011010011001111"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution based on zerkms answer, this deals with the loss of leading 0's when converting decimals back into binary.

```
function compressBitArray(array $bitArray){
    $byteChunks = array_chunk($bitArray, 8);

    $asciiString = implode('', array_map(function($i) {
        return chr(bindec(implode('', $i)));
    },$byteChunks));   

    $encoded = base64_encode($asciiString).'#'.count($bitArray);
    return $encoded;
}


//decode
function decompressBitArray($compressedString){
    //extract origional length of the string
    $parts = explode('#',$compressedString);
    $origLength = $parts[1];

    $asciiChars = str_split(base64_decode($parts[0]));
    $bitStrings = array_map(function($i) {
        return decbin(ord($i));
    }, $asciiChars);

    //pad lost leading 0's
    for($i = 0; $i < count($bitStrings); $i++){
        if($i == count($bitStrings)-1){
            $toPad = strlen($bitStrings[$i]) + ($origLength - strlen(implode('', $bitStrings)));
            $bitStrings[$i] = str_pad($bitStrings[$i], $toPad, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        }else{
            if(strlen($bitStrings[$i]) < 8){
                $bitStrings[$i] = str_pad($bitStrings[$i], 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
            }
        }
    }

    $bitArray = str_split(implode('', $bitStrings));
    return $bitArray;
}
```